# Como remover marcadores de um mapa com a API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para projetar rotas a partir de dados coletados por um sistema embarcado com GPS. Meu servidor recebe coordenadas de diferentes equipamentos e estou gravando isto no meu banco de dados.

O que já me ajudou muito foi [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686811/show-path-on-google-map-use-roads) no StackOverflow-en.

Nesta questão encontrei o código da minha aplicação bem como uma pequena correção para que se adeque as minhas necessidades.

A minha dúvida é como remover Marcadores do mapa.

Na imagem abaixo tenho um resultado proveniente da execução do meu aplicativo:
[image]

Gostaria de torna-lo como mostra a imagem editada abaixo (Sem marcadores intermediários, somente marcadores *start* e *end*):

[image]

Durante minha pesquisa para resolver este problema encontrei várias possíveis soluções, dentre as que me pareceram plausíveis encontrei esta, que é adicionar o seguinte código para remover todos marcadores.

```
for (i = 0;i < markers.length;i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Sei que com umas mudanças na variável `i` que poderia começar com `i = 1` e a condição `i <= markers.length` poderia ser possível preservar os marcadores *start* e *end*, mas não entendo porque isto não esta removendo marcadores.

Comment: Qual código você está tentando? Com relação a correção no `i`, a condição de parada seria `i < markers.length-1` e não `i <= markers.length`, talvez isso esteja retornando um erro e "pareça" que não está funcionando...

Comment: Eduardo seguinte... fica meio complicado de sabermos onde está o problema se não temos o código de geração dos marcadores, poste o código javascript que verificamos para você.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo a pergunta do StackOverflow-en ([esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686811/show-path-on-google-map-use-roads)), o que fica no array markers[] é só objetos com a informação para criar as markers, e não instâncias de google.maps.Marker.

Tens que guardar a instância de google.maps.Marker num array quando as crias (vê [este exemplo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove?hl=pt-PT));

Pegando no exemplo de código [que seguiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686811/show-path-on-google-map-use-roads), o que tens de fazer é:

```
    var markers_inst = [];
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });

        markers_inst.push(marker);

        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
```

Depois disso já podes remover as markers:

```
for (i = 1;i < markers_inst.length-1;i++) {
    markers_inst[i].setMap(null);
}
```